# Ubuntu error - Would not even load from BIOS at times

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, dpkg

I am quite new to Ubuntu. I am not sure what went wrong, all of a sudden I get this error when I try the command `sudo apt-get update`

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I also used `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-distro-info (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.28); however:
  Version of python3-distupgrade on system is 1:18.04.38.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
 update-manager-core depends on python3-update-manager (= 1:20.04.10.1); however:
  Version of python3-update-manager on system is 1:18.04.11.13.
 update-manager-core depends on python3-distro-info; however:
  Package python3-distro-info is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libtinfo6:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.28); however:
  Version of python3-distupgrade on system is 1:18.04.38.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libffi7:amd64 (3.3-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-debconf:
 python3-debconf depends on debconf (= 1.5.66ubuntu1); however:
  Version of debconf on system is 1.5.73.

dpkg: error processing package python3-debconf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-manager-core (= 1:18.04.11.13); however:
  Version of update-manager-core on system is 1:20.04.10.1.
 update-manager depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk; however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3-distro-info; however:
  Package python3-distro-info is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libreadline8:amd64 (8.0-4) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Setting up libncursesw6:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3-distupgrade; however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.18-1~20.04) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-distro-info
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 update-manager-core
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 python3-debconf
 update-manager
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-update-manager
```

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug under Xenial.

please try:

```
cd /var/cache/app-info/xmls/ && sudo rm -iv fwupd.xml; cd

sudo appstreamcli refresh --force

sudo apt update
```

if did not work try:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you. I also used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980420/10370121